# call microsoft cognitive services translator with python

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I now try the following code from azure notebook in python3
     import requests

```
# Getting the key from tab Keys on Azure portal
 key = "xxxxxxxxxxx" 


 url4authentication = 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken'
 headers4authentication = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': key}
 resp4authentication = requests.post(url4authentication,  headers=headers4authentication)
 token = resp4authentication.text

 print(token)
 text="hello there how are you"
 come = "en"
 to = "es"
 url4translate = 'https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/http.svc/Translate'
 from xml.etree import ElementTree
 response = requests.get('https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/http.svc', params = param)
 print(response)
```

and i get the following error:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/nbuser/anaconda3_23/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, **response_kw)
    587             if is_new_proxy_conn:
--> 588                 self._prepare_proxy(conn)
    589 

/home/nbuser/anaconda3_23/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _prepare_proxy(self, conn)
    800 
--> 801         conn.connect()
    802 

/home/nbuser/anaconda3_23/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py in connect(self)
    290             # self._tunnel_host below.
--> 291             self._tunnel()
    292             # Mark this connection as not reusable

/home/nbuser/anaconda3_23/lib/python3.4/http/client.py in _tunnel(self)
    856             raise OSError("Tunnel connection failed: %d %s" % (code,
--> 857                                                                message.strip()))
    858         while True:

OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as reference, I suggest first you can try to refer to my answer for the other similar SO thread [Response from Microsoft Translate API in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41795994/response-from-microsoft-translate-api-in-python/) to resolve your issue. If you have more concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Now i have another error: OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Any idea what can it be

Comment: @hinda Please update the content about the code with `OSError` in your post and what happended in details.